# How to make flickering white spots and moving effects in After Effect

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I want to know how to make those particle-like spots and you see the transparent effects and the fast moving text? I want to know what that effect is called and how to make it. Please help me!(Please watch the video first)
Also, how do I make that smoke effect behind the text?

Answer (score 1):

Stock footage. The spots and fast moving text are from old film leaders. When you are projecting film the first dozen feet or so is the "leader" it protects the inner film from dust and scratches, and lets you thread the projector. It often has the name of the reel written on it. That's what you're seeing over the video.

Prelinger film archive has plenty of old films with leaders, many of which are in the public domain. Composite one over your footage with the luma inverted, and adjust the brigtness / contrast and opacity until you get the look you want.

The "smoke" is probably ink in water. It's a common stock footage effect.

Answer (score 0):

The stock footage that Stib is referring to is being overlaid on top of the original footage using a different composition mode - maybe multiply, overlay, or screen.  Try out several and see which works for you.

https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/6-useful-blending-modes-effects/

The text is being inverted by the footage behind it - could be achieved using Invert and Stencil Alpha